# Starting Jupyter notebook on a node of my cluster (High Performance Computation or HPC facility )

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing, hpc, pbs, qsub

I wanted to run jupyter notebook on a node of our cluster, **NOT on the login node**. I could remotely run the jupyter notebook on the login node, but it would unnecessarily slow down the cluster usage. Please guide me how I can start the jupyter notebook on a node from my local desktop. Our cluster uses **PBS** job submission method, e.g. use use the commands like `qsub`, `qstat`, `qdel` to manage our jobs on the cluster.

Comment: I am not sure if my cluster permits interactive node usage. But I can ssh to a node (say node1) and start jupyter notebook there. The problem in this method is that the node is not blocked and anyone can submit a job on that node. Following the the link
https://dev.to/rohitfarmer/how-to-run-jupyter-notebook-in-an-interactive-node-on-a-high-performance-computer-hpc-27mg

how can I claim a node on my cluster, which follows PBS job submission, to use it in interactive mode?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to reach the person who manages our cluster right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by running a jupyter notebook in a jobscript. The output of the jupyter startup script can be written to a file to get the `token` and monitor the logs.

An example script which worked in my system was:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N Notebook
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=24
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -q medium

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/python
NOTEBOOK_LOGFILE=jupyterlog.out

$PYTHONPATH/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8890 >> ${NOTEBOOK_LOGFILE} 2>&1
```

You could monitor the output by
`tail -f jupyterlog.out` and get the token id.

You could then forward and listen to the port running the jupyter notebook in your local system by,

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:node:8890 user@host
```

Comment: What would be the python path here?

Comment: @lsr729 It's the path of the directory where jupyter is installed, ie, the directory which contains the bin directory containing jupyter executable. An example would be, if jupyter executable path is `/usr/bin/jupyter`, then `PYTHONPATH=/usr`

Comment: On the cluster, the jupyter file is located at `/home/lsr/.local/bin/jupyter`. So in the 3rd from the last line do I need to put `PYTHONPATH=/home/lsr/.local/bin/jupyter` ?

Comment: @lsr729 No it should be `PYTHONPATH=/home/lsr/.local`. Because in the last line we are including the rest of the path as `$PYTHONPATH/bin/jupyter`.

Comment: This worked, I got the password for jupyter. But then when tried to run the `ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:node:8890 user@host` on my local computer, got the error:    
`bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.`

Comment: I think it should be `localhost8890` instead of `localhost8888`

Comment: @lsr729 Did you replace `user@host` with the corresponding username and hostname of your cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216463/discussion-between-lsr729-and-rashid).