# Run Jupyter Notebook from SSH to remote server node

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, gpu, remote-server

I want to run a jupyter notebook from SSH to remote server node.
Steps:

1. ssh user@remote.server
2. jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8887

Steps on my computer:

1. ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8887 user@remote.server
2. run localhost:8888

This works fine. However I want to run this on node1 that is inside user@remote.server, because node1 contains a GPU.

Steps I have done are similar except for this:
ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8887 user@remote.server "ssh node1"

But this does not work: "channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

Edit: /etc/hosts:
[image]

Solution after several attempts, following the answer of @ajz34:

1. On node1: jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8886 --ip=127.0.0.1
2. On server: ssh -N -L 8887:127.0.0.1:8886 node1
3. On local: ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8887 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a possible simple solution could be adding an intermediate ssh connection.

Given your workflow is computer -> server (accessing node) -> node1 (computing node), then

- From user@remote.node1, execute

  `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8886`
- From user@remote.server, execute

  `ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8886 user@remote.node1`
- From your computer, execute

  `ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8887 user@remote.server`

  Then run localhost:8888 on your computer browser.

From the resolution of @CasellaJr, perhaps for different servers, you may wish to explicitly change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `[::1]` or other addresses that may work.

Comment: In case the computing node (node1) could not assign requested localhost address, adding `--ip=127.0.0.1` after `jupyter notebook ...` could avoid this problem. I've just encountered this problem on my HPC environment.

Comment: I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431456/7740992. If computing node is not accessible by ssh but could by LSF, then an LSF script is required.

Comment: I continue to have this error: channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Comment: To be sure, I have done this: in the conda env of my node1: `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8886 --ip=127.0.0.1` then in my server: `ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8886 user@ip node1` and on my local PC: `ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8887 user@ip`

Comment: I think that I have followed your advice but it does not work. Note that the error `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused` appears on the terminal in which I write `ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8886 user@ip node1`

Comment: @CasellaJr I'd admit the error of connection refused is not occurring on my workaround. Perhaps this is rather an ssh error. I'm not sure whether following discussion helps. https://serverfault.com/questions/489192/ssh-tunnel-refusing-connections-with-channel-2-open-failed

Comment: @CasellaJr I then encountered this `channel 2` and `channel 3` in a strange way =,= If three bash commands are not executed sequentially (node1->server->PC), then this error could occur.

Comment: in /etc/hosts of server (and also node1) I have the output in the image (I edited the original message with a picture)

Comment: Maybe i have to substitute "localhost" with 127.0.0.1 when I am inside the server and substitute `--ip=xxx.xx.x.xxx` when I run the jupyter command inside the node1?

Comment: @CasellaJr I'm not sure but in my workaround using "localhost" inside the server is okay >.<

Comment: Maybe i will post the same question also on serverfault ;(

Comment: OMG now is working. I will edit the original post with the code I have used, so you can edit your answer and I will accept it ;)

Comment: Good to hear that a resolution has been found! Great ≥w≤ From your resolution, I guess perhaps explicitly changing localhost to ip address is better.